# How to check if two elements are side by side in multidimentional array in javaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

i will go straight to the point.. So i have created a multidimentional array and i have it like this:

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var sArr = [];

    for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {

        cell = Object.create(cellObj)

        sArr.push(cell);

    }

    arr.push(sArr);

}
```

And about the cellObj, i created it like this:

```
var cellObj = {

state: 0,
img: ""

};
```

Now that i have everything setup, i generate two images in the multidimentional array like this:

```
//the array imgs contain two images

for (var l = 0; l < imgs.length; l++) {

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr[x].length);

    //here is a test to make sure that the two images are in two separate cells

    if (arr[x][y].state === 0) {

        arr[x][y].state = 3;

        arr[x][y].img = imgs[l];

    }
    else
    {
        l--;
    }

}
```

the two images can be on the same row or column with an empty cell between them but i dont want them to be side by side horizontally or vertically.

I hope a nice day to everyone, thank's.

Comment: So you want the images diagnol? Have you tried using position coordinates?

Comment: Create another pair of `x` and `y` and veryfy that `(x1 != x2) && (y1 != y2)`. Pay attention to the limits of `Math.random()` you want it from 0 to 11.

Comment: Hi, yes like that but i dont know how to get the position of my elemnts.

Comment: @Daniel Möller I didn't understand why i would create another x and y..can you explain this because i'm not very good with js

Comment: can images be present horizontally in single row but with a gap of 1 cell

Comment: @ Helping hand Hi, yes they can.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you're looking for is to eliminate those options up front. In the method below, I'm creating a flat array that contains all positions in your array (I've renamed `arr` to `arrayOfImages` for clarity) and naming it `coordLookup`. Once you place an image, the positions next to it vertically and horizontally are removed from `coordLookup` in the filter statement. I've increased the number of test images to show that it's maintaining that spacing - just be aware that if you try to place more images than the array has room to accomodate, it will start to fail, so be sure to add error handling for that case.

(To see this in action, open your console and run the code snippet, it should present the completed array as a table.)

```js
var cellObj = {
state: 0,
img: ""
};

var arrayOfImages = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var sArr = [];

    for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {

        cell = Object.create(cellObj)

        sArr.push(cell);

    }

    arrayOfImages.push(sArr);

}

var coordLookup = [], i = 10, j = 10 //create coordinate lookup
while(--i > -1){
  j = 10
  while(--j > -1){
    coordLookup.push([i,j])
  }
}

var imgs = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']

for (var l = 0; l < imgs.length; l++) {

  let pairIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * coordLookup.length),
    pair = coordLookup[pairIndex],
    x = pair[0], y = pair[1]
  //insert image
   arrayOfImages[x][y].state = 3;
   arrayOfImages[x][y].img = imgs[l]
  //disable horizontal and vertical neighbor cells
  const prevX = x - 1, nextX = x + 1, prevY = y - 1, nextY = y + 1
  
  coordLookup = coordLookup.filter(coordpair => {
    const _x = coordpair[0], _y = coordpair[1],
      isMatch = (_y == y && _x >= prevX && _x <= nextX) || (_x == x && _y >= prevY && _y <= nextY)
    
    return !isMatch
  })
}

//display results
console.table(arrayOfImages.map(row => row.map(cell => JSON.stringify(cell))))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the effort making this, but isn't there a more simple way to resolve my question ??

Comment: @codeLearner This is the most straightforward method that I can think of, it's way more efficient to eliminate those positions from the available choices than to try to place an image, check to see if it belongs there, then try again if it doesn't (also your initial code example has the dangerous potential for an infinite loop by decrementing your loop counter). The more images you add to your multidimensional array, the more complex and time consuming the calculations would become to figure out which spots are still open.